# Map mysqli_fetch_assoc to object attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc to get the database columns of one user (username, password, firstname, lastname ... ect).

I have these same columns as attributes in my user class. I was wondering if there is an easy way of mapping the values of the associated array to the object attributes everytime I call mysqli_fetch_assoc.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work:

```
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc(...);
foreach($user as $key=>$value) {
    $userObject->$key = $value;
}
```

Note the `->$key` - this means to get the property referenced by the contents of the variable `key`.